# How to access the output of a usb fingerprint reader?

Tags: windows, usb, fingerprint

I want to make a password manager (for windows) using a fingerprint reader as a validator, but I want to make it from scratch. I want to take the output of the usb  fingerprint reader (I don't know exactly the format of the output, but I guess is a grayscale image) and process it (using my own fingerprint comparison algorithm).

I've searched on google and youtube, but I only found fingerprint readers with their own comparison algorithm and software.
Can you please help me with some examples of fingerprints readers that gives you the output and some tutorials in which describes how they access the it in real time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows has something called the **Windows Biometric Framework** which you should be able to program to and which should do all the heavy lifting for you, see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secbiomet/biometric-service-api-portal

So just look for a reader supporting that (which is probably all of them).

I hope you don't mind me saying this, but MS (or perhaps the hardware vendor) can probably write a better comparison algorithm than you and doing things this way means that you'll get the same matches (or not) as, say, Windows' own logon procedure.  Imagine the confusion you would sow in the minds of your users if you didn't.

Comment: Thank you, I will check your documentation. For sure they did a good job than I will ever do alone, but I want to make this my final year project and I try to use as less libraries as I can. I planned to use only a library to load the image and OpenCV to parse/process it.

Comment: Strong recommentation: Make your final year project to learn how to use that API, you'll get better marks.  And it's not a library, it's part of Windows.  _`OpenCV`_ is a library!

Comment: Any time, have fun.

Comment: Did you manage to use the API? I haven't managed to get it to work for me.